# PHP String Manipulation, possibly RegEx?

Tags: php, regex, string

`$personInfo['mantra']` is the piece that I'm working with.  I want everything to be capitalized, with the **exception** of prepositions and articles (e.g. 'a', 'an', 'the', etc.)  Is there an efficient way to do this? I'm doing this as `ucwords(strtolower($personInfo['mantra']))` so far, but obviously this does not take into account the prepositions and articles remaining lowercase.

A mantra is all capitalized (e.g. 'I LIVE THE WAY I WANT') in the database, and there are thousands, so it is not practical to manually change them.  To provide an example, I would like the sentence: 'I LIVE THE WAY I WANT' to become 'I Live the Way I Want'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't seem an easy task for regex. As there's not many that prepositions and articles, can't you just use a straight str_replace after ucwords() ?

```
$personInfo['mantra'] = ucwords(strtolower($personInfo['mantra']));
$personInfo['mantra'] = " " . $personInfo['mantra'] . " ";
$personInfo['mantra'] = str_replace(
  array(" An ", " A ", " The "), 
  array(" an ", " a ", " the "), 
$personInfo['mantra']);
$personInfo['mantra'] = trim($personInfo['mantra']);
```

Adding spaces to the beginning and end of each 'mantra' helps to make sure str_replace can replace properly.

You could simplify it by putting all needed prepositions and articles in an array, looping through it and doing it a str_replace on each one. A regex alternative using preg_replace_callback would be possible if needed, but I think it would be both slower and more complex.

Comment: Sounds like this is probably gonna be the best case, I'll accept it after timer expires. :)

Comment: `str_replace()` supports arrays: `str_replace( array( ' A ', ' An ', ' The ' ), array( ' a ', ' an ', ' the ' ), $personInfo[ 'mantra' ] )` (also notice that the words are not all uppercase anymore at this point).

Answer (score 1):

Here's kind of a slower, brute-force way to handle it.  Not very elegant, but it would get the job done:

```
<?php

$articles = array("a","an","the");
$prepositions = array("under","over","beside",etc...);
foreach($mantras as $key => $mantra) {
    $words = explode(" ", strtolower($mantra));
    $newmantra = "";
    foreach($words as $word) {
        if (!in_array($word, $articles) && !in_array($word, $prepositions)) {
            $newmantra .= ucfirst($word)." ";
        } else {
            $newmantra .= $word." ";
        }
    }
    $mantras[$key] = rtrim($newmantra);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go with your ucwords snippet first, and then use the replace function of your database system (which is ?) to search and replace prepositions.

Answer (score 0):

my approach to this would be to define an array with prepositions, and upercase all the words except those.

But this would be more complex than a one liner.

regexp is no solution here i believe.